# Cordova no standby smartphone

Tags: cordova, audio, smartphone

I have developed a corded app for a radio station where you can listen to broadcasts.
now after some time the smartphones go dark (go to standby) and after a while the audio is also interrupted.
How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this by using the [insomnia plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin#readme)